# Cannot sink to Postgres with KSQL table

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

I cannot sink to postgres with KSQL table

I created a KSQL table with some aggregation from a stream (the source topic is Avro). I can see the data with SELECT. I can also sink the topic directly to postgres. However I cannot sink to Postgres for KSQL table. How do I specify the value.converter?

I created the KSQL table like:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table AS SELECT customer_name, COUNT(*) as cnt  FROM some_stream GROUP BY customer_name;
```

I tried connect config like:

```
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
auto.evolve=true
tasks.max=1
topics=some_table
auto.create=true
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb?user=postgres&password=postgres
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
```

The error is:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:514)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:491)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:322)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:226)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:194)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize data for topic some_topic to Avro: 
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:107)
```

I also tried:

```
{
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
  "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "auto.evolve": "true",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "topics": "some_topic",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "auto.create": "true",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb?user=postgres&password=postgres",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
}
```

The error is:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:514)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:491)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:322)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:226)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:194)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error:
```

So how to sink with JdbcSinkConnector for a KSQL table?

Comment: did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check your schema-registry whether it is online and you set right url at `value.converter.schema.registry.url`.